# Vue v-model bind is not working in unit test

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-test-utils

i'm trying to check `#username` element value when i change data `form.username`

```
// Regitser.vue

...
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           id="username"
           v-model="form.username" />
</div>

...

<script>
export default {
    name: "RegisterPage",
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                username: "",
                emailAddress: "",
                password: ""
            }
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

This is test code

```
// Test 
describe("RegisterPage.vue", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let fieldUsername;
    let fieldEmailAddress;
    let fieldPassword;
    let buttonSubmit;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(RegisterPage);
        fieldUsername = wrapper.find("#username");
        fieldEmailAddress = wrapper.find("#emailAddress");
        fieldPassword = wrapper.find("#password");
        buttonSubmit = wrapper.find('form button[type="submit"]');
    });

    it("should have form inputs bound with data model", () => {
        const username = "sunny";
        const emailAddress = "sunny@taskagile.com";
        const password = "VueJsRocks!";

        wrapper.vm.form.username = username;
        wrapper.vm.form.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        wrapper.vm.form.password = password;
        expect(fieldUsername.element.value).toEqual(username);
        expect(fieldEmailAddress.element.value).toEqual(emailAddress);
        expect(fieldPassword.element.value).toEqual(password);
    });
```

and run it, it failed

```
// Test failed
RegisterPage.vue › should have form inputs bound with data model

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "sunny"
    Received: ""

      52 |         console.log(wrapper.find("#username").element.value);
      53 | 
    > 54 |         expect(fieldUsername.element.value).toEqual(username);
         |                                             ^
      55 |         expect(fieldEmailAddress.element.value).toEqual(emailAddress);
      56 |         expect(fieldPassword.element.value).toEqual(password);
      57 |     });

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/RegisterPage.spec.js:54:45)
```

I put 'sunny' in form.username but element not changed
how i fix it?

Comment: Check https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/setData.html#setdata

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but I arrived here because I hit this exact issue while working through book 'Building Applications with Spring 5 with VueJS 2'. The problem is that the book code is based on older versions of Vue and vue-utils, if you used the package.json from the book repo then things would probably have worked.

However, if like me you were working along with the latest Vue CLI then you end up here! And @Estradiaz was correct in his comment. Here is reworked test:

```
it('should have form inputs bound with data model', async () => {
  const username = 'sunny'
  const emailAddress = 'sunny@local'
  const password = 'VueJsRocks'
  await wrapper.setData({
    form: {
      username: username,
      emailAddress: emailAddress,
      password: password
    }
  });
  expect(fieldUsername.element.value).toEqual(username)
  expect(fieldEmailAddress.element.value).toEqual(emailAddress)
  expect(fieldPassword.element.value).toEqual(password)
})
```